# How can i enforce DRY when using Redux Toolkit asyncThunkCreator

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

i have a RTK related question, as i want to be able to cancel any request made i find myself repeating code in most of my action creators created with createAsyncThunk

I would like to make a wrapper of sort but i am having problem typescripting it, is the arguments used in createAsyncThunk exposed somewhere or?

diggin in the code i see the thunkAPI (which is the one im most interested in) is defined with GetThunkAPI<'3rd parameter'> with the 3 typescript parameter

an action creator could look something like this

```
export const resendValidationKey = createAsyncThunk<
  void,
  IAdminResendValidationKey,
  { rejectValue: AxiosError }
>('admin/resendValidationKey', async (data, thunkAPI) => {
  const { signal, rejectWithValue } = thunkAPI;
  try {
    const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
    signal.addEventListener('abort', () => {
      source.cancel();
    });
    await const response = axios.post(`admin/account/validate/resend`, data, {
      cancelToken: source.token,
    });
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    return rejectWithValue(error);
  }
});
```

ideally i would want some sort ofa wrapper i just feed the url, method, data and success callback (if any), is that even possible?

Hope this all makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

I created a wrapper around `createAsyncThunk` as follows:

```ts
import type { AsyncThunkPayloadCreator } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
//...

const handleReduxResult = async <T>(
    actionName: string,
    fn: () => T | Promise<T>,
    rejectWithValue: (value: unknown) => unknown,
) => {
    try {
        return await fn();
    } catch (e: unknown) {
        const wrappedError = wrapErrorTyped(e);
        wrappedError.actionName = actionName;
        const wrappedSerializedError = createWrappedSerializedError(wrappedError);
        return rejectWithValue(wrappedSerializedError) as T;
    }
};

export interface CustomAsyncThunkConfig {
    [prop: string]: unknown;
}

export const createCustomAsyncThunk = <Returned, ThunkArg = void>(
    name: string,
    thunk: AsyncThunkPayloadCreator<Returned, ThunkArg, CustomAsyncThunkConfig>,
) =>
    createAsyncThunk<Returned, ThunkArg, CustomAsyncThunkConfig>(
        name,
        async (params, thunkApi) =>
            await handleReduxResult(
                name,
                async () => thunk(params, thunkApi),
                thunkApi.rejectWithValue,
            ),
    );
```

In my case I want to handle custom errors that can be thrown by the function called in the thunk, but redux toolkit creates their own error instead, that is thrown when the thunk result is unwrapped, which is a no go in our setup.

It can be avoided by calling the function `rejectWithValue` present in the second parameter of the thunk function, but unfortunately having to call that every time would be very bad, having to include a lot of boilerplate.

To circumvent that we created a wrapper around `createAsyncThunk` which is not very straightforward because the types used by it are very complex and many of them are not exported.

In any case, I was able to create a wrapper that calls the function `handleReduxResult`, which is the function that handles the error, creating a custom error in the format we use for errors, and also including the `actionName` to give more context about the error in the logs, and we finally serialize it and send to `rejectWithValue` (which expects a serialized value).

The error handling is specific to our case, you can change the `handleReduxResult` function to some minimal code like:

```ts
const handleReduxResult = async <T>(
    actionName: string,
    fn: () => T | Promise<T>,
    rejectWithValue: (value: unknown) => unknown,
) => {
    return await fn();
};
```

and then make the changes according to your use case.